# Using Variable Names in Functions [R]

Tags: r

Working in R I would like to make a function that calculates a weighted percentage for a dummy variable. I can't figure out how to use variables (field) names in a function. Am I stumbling on the scope of variables (Global vs local environments)?

Using the mtcars dataset as an example, let's say I want to calculate the percentage of cars with "vs" value 0, using the "carb" field as the weight for each observation.

I've tried the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

binary_perc <- function(set, var_name) {
  count_tbl <- dplyr::count(set, var_name, wt = carb)
  yes <- as.numeric(count_tbl[1,2])
  total <- as.numeric(sum(count_tbl$n))
  perc <- round((yes/total)*100, 1)
  return(perc)
}

vs_perc <- binary_perc(mtcars, vs)
```

However, when I run the function I get the error below:

```
 Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `var_name` is not found.
```

Why isn't the function swapping in "vs" for var_name when it runs? I have also tried putting "vs" in quotes as a string when I call the function to the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: This is due to R's use of non standard evaluation - quoting and unquoted expressions for tidyverse packages like dplyr. Try wrapping the variable name in "curly curly" notation in the function: count({{set}}, {{var_name}})

Comment: Thank you @aranglol it worked! What exactly does the {{ }} notation do?

Comment: It's shorthand for !!enquo(). Please see this link here for more information, since I barely understand it myself. 

https://www.r-bloggers.com/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/